# node-sass: command not found after installing globally

Tags: sass, node-sass

I had `node sass` installed globally on my machine previously then after a reset I had to reinstall.

I have tried installing it globally as I use it to compile `.scss` files in specific directories. After trying to install it globally and reinstall it globally it does not work. I did this on a separate machine and it works without issues.

Tried the following:

```
npm i node-sass -g
npm install node-sass
npm install -g node-sass
```

> $ node-sass -v
>
> bash: node-sass: command not found

Comment: Add global npm location to your PATH environment variable. Than you can run global packages from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `npx` to run node-sass. `npx` will check if you have a global path to the `npm` package, and if not, it will temporaily download and execute it.

For instance, to run node-sass and check version.

```
npx node-sass -v
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for the version but when trying to compile a sass file it gives me the following error:

fs.js:1061
  return binding.unlink(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Comment: The issue is using windows 10

Comment: Then try opening your CMD with administrator rights. (right click - administrator rights)

Answer (score 3):

I tried installing node-sass globally on my linux PC, then running `node-sass -v` and it worked.
Assuming that you are running your commands on Linux, you might not have your npm home in your $PATH, so your OS doesn't know where to look for when you write `node-sass`.

To solve this look for your npm home folder (where you have installed node-sass), then add that path to the $PATH environment variable.

You can run `npm list -g`, and the first output line is the path of your global npm sources (**the directory you need is bin, not lib**).

You might also want to follow this guide to be able to run npm packages commands as root: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally.
If you do this you should re-install all your global packages in order to have them all in the same directory.

If you are using Windows, is basically the same, only the method of setting the env var changes.